# Эквивалентны ли обычные шаблонные функции сокращённым шаблонным функциям?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, language-lawyer, c++20

Эквивалентны ли следующие записи? И можно ли использовать одно в объявлении, а другое - в определении?

```
void foo(auto x);

template<typename T>
void foo(T x);
```

Я хочу использовать первый краткий вариант в заголовках для пользователей, а второй - в реализации, чтобы можно было легко получить доступ к типу `T` без `decltype`. Легально ли это?

Comment: Пользователям шаблона должно быть доступно определение, так что затея бессмыслена.

Comment: @user7860670 я разделяю шаблоны как и обычные функции на hpp и tpp/ipp

Comment: Тем не менее, определение по-прежнему будет находиться в заголовках для пользователей.

Comment: @user7860670 верно, но идея в том, что пользователь смотрит только hpp, видит краткий интерфейс и не заботится о том, что там дальше включается, так что под "заголовками для пользователей" я имел в виду только hpp

Comment: Дурацкая идея (или говоря наукообразно -- методологически неверная). Суть в том, что чем сильнее вы пытаетесь скрыть истинные типы в системе программирования, тем больше ошибок будет в конечных продуктах

Answer (score 3):

Да, должны быть эквивалентны, судя по [`[dcl.fct]/22`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#22):

> An abbreviated function template is equivalent to a function template ([temp.fct]) whose template-parameter-list includes one invented type template-parameter for each generic parameter type placeholder of the function declaration, in order of appearance.

Но, ИМХО, это плохая идея. Намного удобнее, когда объявление и определение записаны одинаково - можно копипастить одно в другое, если нужно что-то поменять в них. И если кто-то будет искать определение в коде, ему тоже будет проще, если запись будет совпадать.

Comment: Я, кстати, не согласен, что это сильные аргументы против. Копипаст стоит сводить к минимуму, а, например, `clangd` переходит от такого объявления к определению без проблем.

Comment: @tocic Плохо копипастить *логику*. Сигнатуру функции заставляет копипастить язык, от этого не избавиться. Про Clangd - это все хорошо, но иногда хочется по-быстрому посмотреть что-то в коде - либо прямо в браузере, либо в свеже склонированном репозитории, не разбираясь с тем,  как сгенерировать `compile_commands.json`.

Comment: Это да, но я про то, что IDE позволяют рефакторить и перемещаться по коду без копипаста. Справедливости ради, `clangd` смог поменять название функции, но не смог поменять название параметра в данном случае.

Comment: @tocic А clangd умеет сам генерировать определение, чтобы руками не копипастить?

Comment: Чистый `clangd` вроде бы не умеет. Но CLion, который под капотом его использует, — да. Нашёл feature request https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/445.

Answer (score 2):

Технически вы правы и они эквивалентны (лучший вид правоты :)).

[[dcl.fct]/18](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.fct#18):

> ... An abbreviated function template is **equivalent** to a function
> template
> ([[temp.fct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/temp.fct))
> whose *template-parameter-list* includes one invented type
> *template-parameter* for each generic parameter type placeholder of the function declaration, in order of appearance. ...

Однако есть как минимум две проблемы, из-за которых я бы не рекомендовал одновременное использование разных видов шаблонных функций.

1. С практической точки зрения, [`clang` и `msvc` принимают следующий код, а `gcc` — нет](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:9),source:%27void+foo(auto)%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Avoid+foo(T)+%7B%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B+%0A++++foo(42)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.18939393939395,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:g131,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:clang1600,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_35_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2B20%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+3/15%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.81060606060606,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

```cpp
void foo(auto);

template <typename T>
void foo(T) {}

int main() { 
    foo(42);
}
```

> error: call of overloaded 'foo(int)' is ambiguous

2. Это вряд ли будет исправлено, т.к. с большой вероятностью в указанном пункте стандарта имеется в виду не эквивалентность, а функциональная эквивалентность, что означает, что программа *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*.

[[temp.over.link]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/temp.over.link#7):

> ... If the validity or meaning of the program depends on whether two
> constructs are equivalent, and they are functionally equivalent but
> not equivalent, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Это следует из следующих наблюдений.

- В том же пункте, в котором говорится про эквивалентность, в примере используется функциональная эквивалентность.

[[dcl.fct]/example-7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.fct#example-7):

> ...
>
> These declarations are **functionally equivalent (but not
> equivalent)** to the following declarations.
>
> ...

- В [P0717](https://wg21.link/p0717) обсуждался как раз ваш юзкейс и было принято решение отклонить его (подробнее про голосование см. пункт *Require redeclarations to use consistent syntax* в [P0691](https://wg21.link/p0691)).

> There may occasionally be a desire to declare a function with one
> syntax for readability to their users and define it with a different
> syntax, but doing so requires understanding the details of an arcane
> token rewrite rule so we would not recommend it even to an expert
> user. As a consequence, we recommend removing this deviation from
> normal template rules and that the regular rule for C++ templates be
> used: all declarations of a function template must use the same syntax
> for dependent portions of a template, including in the specification
> of constraints on constrained function templates.

- В репозитории черновика стандарта открыты 2 *issues*, в которых предлагают исправить эту неточность ([1](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/5495) и [2](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/4121)).

---

Подробнее про историю, почему так могло произойти, вы можете почитать в [ответе на аналогичный вопрос с enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63525416/6944845).